# Laravel relationship on a second level pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

Cards:

- id (PK)
- label
- company_user_id (FK, Unique) (Foreign key on column `Companies_Users.id` )

Companies_Users:

- id (PK)
- company_id
- user_uuid

Users:

- uuid (PK)
- name

Companies:

- id (PK)
- name

**Every user can have one card per company. If a user is in multiple companies, he can have multiple cards.**

**Every card can be owned by one and only one user.**

I need to set the relationship on the Card model that would get me the User owning the card.

What I did is:

```
class Card extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'cards';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, CompanyUser::class, "user_uuid", "uuid", "company_user_id", "user_uuid");
    }

}
```

But $card->user is always returning null.

How can I make it so I can fetch the user of a card without doing $card->companyUser->user. I need it to work directly using $card->user.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you need dig into many-to-many relations? Docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: @silentwasd I believe this has to be done through a through relation as the pivot table does not have a direct connection to cards table

Comment: I mean your companies_users table is excatly pivot :)

Comment: You can use hasOneThrough for access card from user

Comment: @silentwasd But this is what I'm using

Comment: In your case 'hasOneThrough' not works. Because your card not have user through companies_users. Your user have card through companies_users. But if you make column card_id in 'companies_users' and make column 'company_user_id' in 'users' it would be work.

Comment: @Lambasoft, @silenteasd is correct. `hasOneThrough` is not to get parent from a child model, it is to get a child from a parent model. actually `hasOneThrough` relation extends `hasManyThrough`

Comment: @Lambasoft 
Seems there is no native relationship in laravel for this requirement
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730418/how-to-inverse-the-eloquent-has-one-and-has-many-through-laravel-5-8